# How to achieve matrix mapping without using for loop using numpy in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have three arrays, a `src` array of shape `(width, height, 3)` , a `template` array of shape `(640, 480, 3)` and an `img_map` array of shape `(width, height, 2)` .

`img_map` stores the x,y relationship between `src` and `template`, i.e. `src[4, 5] = template[img_map[0,4,5], img_map[1,4,5]]`. When index  suggested by the mapping is out of bound, no value will be assigned.

How to achieve such value assignment without for loop using numpy in python?

Using for loop will be like this, but it is too slow.

```
for x in range(0, width): 
  for y in range(0, height):
    u = img_map[x,y,0]
    v = img_map[x,y,1]
    if (u >= 0) and (v >= 0) and (u < 640) and (v < 480):
      src[x,y,:] = template[u,v,:]
```

Comment: `src[v, u]` Whats (v, u) ?

Comment: if `img_map.shape` is `(width, height, 2)` then `img_map[1,4,5]` will always throw an error.  please make sure your code is runnable before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one liner version that should do the job:

```
src = template[img_map[:,:,0].ravel(),img_map[:,:,1].ravel(),:].reshape((width,height,3))
```

Here is a small code that verify the accuracy of results and evaluate the performance improvement:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Preparation of testdata
(width, height, depth) = (1000, 1000, 3)
template = np.random.randint(0, 256, (640,480,depth))
img_map = np.concatenate((
    np.random.randint(0, template.shape[0], (width*height,1)),
    np.random.randint(0, template.shape[1], (width*height,1))
  ), axis=1
).reshape(width,height,2)

# For loop verion
t_start = time.time()
src = np.zeros((img_map.shape[0],img_map.shape[1],template.shape[2]))
for x in range(0, img_map.shape[0]): 
  for y in range(0, img_map.shape[1]):
    u = img_map[x,y,0]
    v = img_map[x,y,1]
    if (u >= 0) and (v >= 0) and (u < template.shape[0]) and (v < template.shape[1]):
      src[x,y,:] = template[u,v,:]
print(f'Timer 1: {time.time()-t_start}s')

# One line version
t_start = time.time()
src2 = template[img_map[:,:,0].ravel(),img_map[:,:,1].ravel(),:].reshape((width,height,depth))
print(f'Timer 2: {time.time()-t_start}s')

# Verify that both gives the same result
print('Results are equal' if np.linalg.norm(src-src2)==0 else 'Results differ')
```

The results are equal and the execution time is significantly improved:

```
% python3 script.py
Timer 1: 2.7333829402923584s
Timer 2: 0.0499570369720459s
Results are equal
```

Don't hesitate if you have questions.